# SQL debug in vs code

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS code tool on windows and exploring the functionality. So far, i'd say it is an awesome tool which has some cool features than traditional SSMS. The difficulty I'm facing is, usage of debug in VS Code.

When I click the debug, it is giving me blank side windows next to activity bar like callstack,breakpoints etc., and it seems like standard vs code installer supports only 4 languages. I am not able to see SQL in the bar.

Can anyone guide me on HOWTO debug the SQL objects like stored procs, functions inside the console?

Thanks

Comment: I won't help on your case, but you might be interested in SQL Ops based on VS code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017