# Debugging T-SQL in VS Code

Tags: t-sql, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm exploring VS Code.  I would like to debug a stored procedure but when I search extensions for '@category:debuggers SQL' there are no results.  I 'Started Debugging' and clicked 'Find SQL Extension' and again no results.  The Debug Console is blank/empty.  Is it possible to debug SQL in VS Code?  I'm familiar with this post but it's many years old so asking again.
[SQL debug in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070834/sql-debug-in-vs-code)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM6Y6.png)

Comment: You can use Azure Data Studio, which is based on VS Code and use the SQL Database Projects extension.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on next steps?  I have Azure Data Studio opened and I've downloaded the SQL Database Projects extension.  I've looked all around for a debug menu but don't see anything (see attached pic of menu options).  I also searched the Command Palette for 'debug' but no results.

Comment: By debugging, do you mean to execute said T-SQL scripts to see results from the database in VS Code? Like you would within SSMS (for example)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I want to step through the code and be able to use the Watch window to see variable values.

Comment: Did you ever solve this using VS Code, or Azure Data Studio? SSMS  v17.9.1 is the last version supporting debug (it was removed thereafter ) so a solution with a current tool is helpful.